# php serialization format when implementing Serializable interface

Tags: php, serialization

I understand the serialization format for objects but want to understand the format when Serializable interface is implemented

For example when I serialize an object I get property name as well

```
"O:21:"Concepts\Cache\Rumble":1:{s:27:"\000Concepts\Cache\Rumble\000data";s:8:"database";}"
```

But when I implement `Serializable` I get

```
string(49) "C:21:"Concepts\Cache\Rumble":15:{s:8:"database";}"
```

What do I need to do if I want to have property names also in above output?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the `Serializable` interface is [deprecated in 8.1](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/serializable-deprecated). You should just implement the `__serialize` and `__unserialize` magic methods.

Comment: And see [this documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.serialize) for the correct way to implement `__serialize()`. If you do this correctly, you should get the property names you want.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question.